# argv listing directory files

Tags: python

this very simple code is driving me nuts.

```
import sys,string,socket  

maquina = sys.argv[1]
texto = string.join(sys.argv[2:], " ")
print '['+maquina+']' 
print '['+texto+']'

mysock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
if  maquina == '*':
    for ip in range(18,254):
        mysock.sendto( texto, ('192.168.0.'+str(ip),8090) )
else:
    mysock.sendto( texto, (maquina,8090))
mysock.close()
```

When I type

```
python send.py 192.168.0.135 several strings
```

the output is:

```
[192.168.0.135]
[several strings]
```

But if I type

```
python send.py * several strings
```

I got:

```
[ajax]
[ajustaprofile.py build dia2django.py djangoajax django-cube django-evolution django_excel_templates-0.1 Doc google_appengine httpd.conf imagens jre1.5.0_08 lib list_mailbackup.py luma models.py netsend.py pip-log.txt reverse.py share testparamet.py tnsnames.ora util virttool-0.1 xlrd-0.7.1 xlutils-1.4.1 xlwt-0.7.2 several lines]
```

This is the file list that I have on current directory!
Python translates somehow '*' to the files of current directory.

I tried to do the homework using this link but I got no clue.

http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html
http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/kgp_commandline.html

How can I use "*" on argv ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `'*'` instead of `*`. Your shell feeds results of `*` to the program via cmdline args, just like `ls *`.

Comment: To make it clear, Python isn't doing this; your shell is. The single quotes around an argument prevent the shell from processing it before handing it off to your script.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get file names is using the glob module:

```
>>> from glob import glob
>>> glob('*')
['file1.txt', 'file2.py', 'file3', ... ]
```

It work just like the `ls` command.

Comment: The question asked was how to *prevent* the filenames from getting globbed onto `argv`, not how to do it another way. :-)